# Can't load separate geojson file into javascript variable for Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson

Using Mapbox example store locator, I've built my own version [here](https://jessicachinafile.github.io/#).

However, the Mapbox example has all the geojson data in the html itself, which will get rather unwieldy for my growing dataset.  Instead, I'd like to be able to keep the geojson data separate from the html file.  So I pulled it out into 'test.geojson' and checked to make sure it validates. I read several explanations of how to have the geojson data loaded in from a separate local file (or url), so [I tried this](https://jessicachinafile.github.io/index_sepfiletest.html):

```
//I replaced the geojson data that had previously been in the html with this to try and create a variable that loads the geojson data from a separate file
var stores = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
.loadURL('test.geojson')
.addTo(map);

// This was what was in the original code I got from the mapbox example
map.on('load', function (e) {
map.addSource("places", {
  "type": "geojson",
  "data": stores
});
buildLocationList(stores);
});
```

But as you can see at the link, it doesn't work.  What am I missing in the javascript?